# Quelle préposition utiliser avant un nom d'arrêt de transport en commun ?

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

Dans mon entourage, j'ai remarqué que beaucoup de monde utilise systématiquement la préposition "à" avant le nom d'une station de métro ou d'un arrêt de bus/tramway. Quelques exemples (toulousains) :

> Je descends à Empalot.
>
> On descend à Carmes.
>
> Je prends le tramway à Place Georges Brassens.

L'usage systématique du "à", quelque soit le nombre du nom de la station, me dérange. Par exemple, "Carmes" fait référence au quartier éponyme, dont le nom est systématiquement considéré comme étant un pluriel dans la littérature municipale. J'ai donc tendance à dire "On descend aux Carmes".

De même, lorsque le nom de l'arrêt correspond à un nom de voie routière, l'usage de "à" me semble erroné. Je dis donc "Je prends le tramway Place Georges Brassens", comme je pourrais dire "j'habite Place Georges Brassens".

Un dernier exemple (parisien) : je dis "je prends le métro jusqu'à l'Assemblée Nationale" et non "jusqu'à Assemblée Nationale".

Ma question est la suivante : est-ce que l'usage systématique de "à" avant un nom de station est correct ou vis-je dans l'erreur ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le nom de l'arrêt est un nom propre qui est régi par ses propres règles. La préposition "à" est là pour dire que l'on parle bien de l'arrêt de métro/tram/... et non pas du quartier, de la rue, etc. où il se trouve.

Pour prendre les exemples donnés. Le quartier des Carmes fait 29 km<sup>2</sup>. Où est-ce qu'on va si on s'arrête "aux Carmes" ? C'est pas clair. Mais si on s'arrête "à Carmes", ça ne peut être que l'arrêt de tram qui s'appelle "Carmes". Ce serait pareil s'il s'agissait d'une très longue rue: quand je prends le tram jusqu'à "Avenue de France", si on ne sait pas qu'il s'agit d'un arrêt de tram, on pourrait se demander où je descends exactement, l'avenue en question étant longue de 1750 m...

Quand l'arrêt se réfère à un lieu bien précis, c'est moins problématique. Par exemple, si on prend le tram place George Brassens, alors ça veut dire que l'on prend le tram à l'arrêt qui se situe sur cette place. Une place, ce n'est pas très grand, donc il n'y a qu'un seul arrêt possible. Mais il y a quand même une subtilité : ça reste différent de si on avait dit "je prends le tram à Place George Brasses", où l'on dit clairement le nom de l'arrêt de tram plutôt que là où il se trouve. (Et on met donc une majuscule à Place.)

Quant à prendre le métro "à l'Assemblée nationale", je dirais qu'il n'y a pas d'arrêt de métro *dans* l'Assemblée nationale, et qu'en fait on prend le métro *devant* cette Assemblée. Donc quitte à être imprécis, autant donner le nom de l'arrêt et dire qu'on prend le métro "à Assemblée nationale". (Car si on avait vraiment voulu être précis, il aurait fallu dire qu'on prend le métro au palais Bourbon, l'Assemblée nationale étant en fait le groupe constitué par les députés, qu'il ne faut pas confondre avec son siège...)

Comment: Je n'avais pas pensé au fait que le nom de l'arrêt est un nom propre spécifique. Merci ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

L'usage systématique de "à" dans cette situation me gêne aussi. Le soir, je descends du métro **aux** Carmes. C'est très clair: il n'y a qu'une station de ce nom dans le quartier éponyme. C'est pareil pour *Arènes*: on prend le métro, le bus, le tramway ou le train **aux** Arènes.

Il m'est arrivé aussi de prendre le métro **à** *Minimes Claude Nougaro* et parfois aussi **aux** Minimes. Dans le premier cas j'utilise le nom de la station, dans le second c'est le nom du quartier desservi par icelle. Le même principe vaut pour *Patte d'oie*: j'entends indifféremment **à** *Patte d'oie* ou **à la** Patte d'oie, selon qu'on désigne la station ou le quartier.

Enfin, je suis déjà descendu du métro **à la** prison, même si la station se nomme *Saint-Michel Marcel Langer* et même si la maison d'arrêt à proximité de la station est desormais désaffectée.

Tout ça pour dire que la règle semble être d'utiliser **à** sans article avec le nom officiel de l'arrêt ou de la station et d'inclure l'article quand on désigne l'arrêt ou la station par le nom du quartier.